# OpenCart 1.5.1 Order confirmation email works in other stores but not the main store

Tags: opencart

I am using OpenCart 1.5.1 and have setup multi-stores - main store and a wholesale store.

The issue I am facing is order confirmation emails are not going from the main store but, it is working on the wholesale store!

Any idea why this could be happening?
I did some searching and I find many posts asking to check safe mode in Plesk but, I do not expect this to be a similar issue since it works on the wholesale store and not the main store.